# Ejb 2.1 Timer service - not honoring timeduration passed- WAS 7.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, websphere, ejb-2.x

I have a weird problem, I am using EJB 2.1 timer object(stateless session bean) to fire a timer at the init() of a servlet.

I call a method to perform some housekeeping stuff in the timeout() method of EJB. I'm not looking for the timer to be cancelled. But I want it running

`Timer myTimer = timerService.createTimer(timeOfDay, myInterval, timername);`

Everything works fine - the timer kicks at the specified time which is now(). It does the house keeping stuff as well. The interval i set there is 5 mins or 300000ms. Here is the problem -- its not honoring the interval i have set there, it timeouts every min or random time within 1 min.

What is the setting I might be missing in the container? Has anyone come across this issue? any suggestion is appreciated.

Server: WAS 7.0 (commerce test server)
Java: 1.5
EJB version: 2.1

Here is the stack trace from the log:

```
0000001d LocalExceptio E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "ejbTimeout" on bean "BeanId(WC#WebSphereCommerceServerExtensionsData.jar#****GlobalTimers, null)". Exception data: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sessionbean.globaltimer.****GlobalTimersBean.ejbTimeout(****GlobalTimersBean.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimedObjectWrapper.ejbTimeout(TimedObjectWrapper.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerTaskHandler.doWork(TimerTaskHandler.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.executeTaskWithNotification(AlarmListener.java:796)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.access$700(AlarmListener.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener$TaskWork.doWork(AlarmListener.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener$TaskWork.run(AlarmListener.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ExecutionContextImpl.go(ExecutionContextImpl.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.fireTask(AlarmListener.java:1401)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.fired(AlarmListener.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.AlarmImpl.callListenerMethod(AlarmImpl.java:340)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.GenericTimer.run(GenericTimer.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1150)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.AlarmImpl.runListenerAsCJWork(AlarmImpl.java:175)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.fireAlarm(_Alarm.java:333)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:230)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)

[4/7/15 23:20:52:344 MDT] 0000001d AlarmListener E   SCHD0063E: A task with ID 352 failed to run on Scheduler WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service (WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service) because of an exception: com.ibm.ejs.container.UnknownLocalException: nested exception is: java.lang.NullPointerException.
[4/7/15 23:20:52:328 MDT] 0000001d FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on J:\WCDE_E~1\wasprofile\logs\ffdc\server1_640a640a_15.04.07_23.20.52.0476810994631708349156.txt com.ibm.ejs.container.LocalExceptionMappingStrategy.setUncheckedException 178
[4/7/15 23:20:52:344 MDT] 0000001d FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on J:\WCDE_E~1\wasprofile\logs\ffdc\server1_640a640a_15.04.07_23.20.52.328399068925450035540.txt com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.TaskWork.fireTask 390
```

Thanks.

Comment: There will be a stack trace in a log file somewhere. Add it to your question

Comment: Updated it with stack trace

Comment: Timers will cancel themselves if they fail too many times.  Your timeout method appears to be failing with NullPointerException.  Why is that happening?  What happens if you fix the NPE?

Comment: verified the server console by using the command `findejbtimers` from the/bin directory of was server. Thanks to @bkail from another post. Realized EJB 2.1 spec only support persistent timers and timers are not cancelled at server shut down. There were existing timer tasks persisted which needs to be cancelled at the server restart, which i did programmatically and the issue was resolved.Basically there shouldnt be daemon threads other than the one created at start up. Noticed that when i printed out `Timer` object in the `ejbtimeout()` method,there was a null reference.

Comment: @Jauyzed You should write that last comment as an answer to your own question (and accept it).